# How to know the previous language used by device

Tags: ios

How to know the previous language used by device?

Depending on it if the previous and current language is not same then I'll update the db and vice-versa

Basically if the previous and current is not same I have to delete the contents of the table and update the table depending on the current language

Comment: I doubt you can, but I don't see why you would need to.  Whenever the language changes can't **you** store that somewhere and then you can do the comparison using that.

Comment: plus; I don't think people change their languages daily.

Comment: @Desdenova that's not the question here.

Comment: If user runs your app, I think it's OK. Just save Language to NSUserDefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can get the previous language by apple api but by the below code you can get the preferred languages as well as current.

```
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *languages = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *preferredLang = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now what I suggest that store the current language in your database or NSUserDefault and and check regularly for current language and match with your database. If you found change that mean the current `preferredLang` is the current language and previous one you can get from your database or NSUserDefault and do what ever you want.